# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm trying to build opencv with `opencv_contrib` on OS X. I will explain step-by-step what I did:

1. I downloaded the OpenCV 3.1 from http://opencv.org/downloads.html
2. I also downloaded the **opencv_contrib** from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib
3. I put the `opencv_contrib` folder inside the `opencv-3.1.0` folder
4. I created a folder called "**build**" inside the `opencv-3.1.0` folder
5. From the terminal I went to the build folder: `/Users/kelvinsp/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build/`
6. Then I ran the following commands:

   ```
   cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/kelvinsp/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/opencv_contrib/modules /Users/kelvinsp/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/ 

   make -j5
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Then, in python terminal I tried to run the command: `import cv2` and receive the following error: `ImportError: No module named cv2`
8. Searching in stackoverflow, I found a solution and I ran the command: `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH`
9. Now the `import cv2` command is working, but when I ran the command `help(cv2.face)` I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'`

Can someone help me please? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a space between  "-D" and "OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=...",
which means "cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/kelvinsp/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/opencv_contrib/modules /Users/kelvinsp/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/ ",
and check there are "face" module to be buildt

Comment: Thanks Kobe Yu. I did the whole process again using a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and it worked.